# How do I deserialize a Json object in C# where the the object contains a Union field?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create a data model in C# for a Google Assistant Argument object ( https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Argument) Here is a snippet of the documentation Google provides at the link. This is the format of the Json object they post to my API.

```
{
  "name": string,
  "rawText": string,
  "textValue": string,
  "status": {
    object(Status)
  },

  // Union field value can be only one of the following:
  "intValue": string,
  "floatValue": number,
  "boolValue": boolean,
  "datetimeValue": {
    object(DateTime)
  },
  "placeValue": {
    object(Location)
  },
  "extension": {
    "@type": string,
    field1: ...,
    ...
  },
  "structuredValue": {
    object
  }
  // End of list of possible types for union field value.
}
```

My confusion comes after the "//Union field value can be only one of the following:".  I don't understand how to deserialize the object to my data model if I don't know what object Google will be sending me.

I've tried to list all the possible types in my model

```
 public class Argument
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rawText")]
        public string RawText { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("textValue")]
        public string TextValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public Status Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("intValue")]
        public int IntValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("floatValue")]
        public float FloatValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("boolValue")]
        public bool BoolValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("datetimeValue")]
        public GoogleDateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("placeValue")]
        public Location PlaceValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("extensions")]
        public KeyValuePair<string, string> Extensions { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("structuredValue")]
        public JObject StructuredValue { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the arguments section of the Json Google is posting to my web API

```
"arguments": [
        {
          "name": "trigger_query",
          "rawText": "what's happening today",
          "textValue": "what's happening today"
        },
        {
          "name": "DATEFIELD",
          "rawText": "today",
          "textValue": "today",
          "dateValue": {
            "year": 2018,
            "month": 10,
            "day": 23
          }
        }
      ]
```

Google should be sending me a date in this particular use case.  When I look at the raw Json above Google is not sending the date in the dateTimeValue like the documentation suggests its sending me a dateValue.  When I add a property for dateValue to my model it works but that doesn't seem to match with the documentation. It doesn't seem like correct and clean code to have all the different types of values when only one is needed.  What is the best way to design the data model

Comment: Does `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` work for you?

Comment: `I've tried to list all the possible types in my model` you left out the most important and relevant part... so what happened, what error did you get

Comment: Frontear - It works but only if I list all of the possible types in my Argument object (ie everything below the comment about union field value).

Comment: TheGeneral - Again no error I can get it to work it just doesn't look / feel like the right way to do it.  It seems like there should be some sort of generic object.  One that could accept any of the possible types that Google lists in their documentation.